# LaravelのSimple QR CODE generate(' ')の中に https://example/kaiiin/show/{id} のURLを入れたい

Tags: laravel

[laravelでQRコードを作成する](https://co.bsnws.net/article/54)

上記サイトで紹介されているプラグイン [simple-qrcode](https://github.com/SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode) を使って、`https://example/kaiiin/show/{id}` のidを付与したページをQRコードで吐き出したいと思っています。

以下、コントローラです。

```
public function show(memnber $member,$id)
    {
      $member = User::find($id);
      return view('kaiin.show',['member' =>$member,'id' => $id]);
    }
```

以下のYour contentの部分にですが、絶対バスは入れられるのですがid付きのURLをどうやって書けばよいのか分からず、困っています。

`{!! QrCode::size(100)->generate('Your content') !!}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravelでアプリ内のフルURLを取得したい場合はUrlGeneratorを使うと簡単に取れます。
また、`url()`ヘルパが活用できます。

#### 現在のページのURL

```
url()->current()
```

#### 任意のURL

```
url()->to('/kaiin/show', ['id' => 100])
```

#### 名前付きルートへのURL

```
(ex: route/web.php)
  Route::get('kaiin/show/{id}', 'KaiinControler@show')->name('kaiin.show');


url()->route('kaiin.show', ['id' => 100])
```

---

ところで例示されているcontrollerの引数`member $member`がなにものなのか気になりますが…

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！！！